# Eclipse Grails - Does not recognize structure from SVN import

Tags: eclipse, svn, grails

I imported a grails project to eclipse via svn and it does not set the view right (project explorer)

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: Try grails tools > refresh dependencies.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Michels first I had to enable the dependency management, did that and also refreshed, but nothing changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the commit had additional information which broke eclipse.
I created a new project from the sources, cleared the repo and made the commit based on [this tutorial on the main list](http://grails.org/Checking+Projects+into+SVN).